# Why can't unrar expand this expression?

Tags: wildcards, rar

I had three RAR files in the same directory: `file1.rar`, `file2.rar` and `file3.rar`. I wanted to extract them with one command using expansion, bearing in mind that asterisks have to be escaped in arguments for `unrar`, `unzip`, `7z`, etc.

I tried this command:

`unrar x file\*rar`

It resulted in:

```
UNRAR 5.00 beta 8 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2013 Alexander Roshal

No files to extract
```

However, this command worked:

`unrar x file\*`

And this command works:

`ls file*rar`

It results in:

`file1.rar file2.rar file3.rar`

So why doesn't the first command work?

Comment: The asterisk is actually *preventing* shell expansion, passing the unexpanded string to `unrar`. So your question is actually why `unrar` doesn't handle that pattern.

Comment: Good point. I'll change the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work in 5.2.7 (newer version) either. I'd suggest trying `unrar x file\*.rar`, note the dot before `rar`. That goes down a slightly different code path, at least in 5.2.7, and it works in 5.2.7.

Why? Well, after a few minutes of looking through unrar's source (take a look at `match.cpp` if you want to try!), I can comfortably say "because Alexander Roshal really, really, *reallly* should have used `glob(3)` instead". Why didn't he? Probably because its not available on Windows, where AFAIK rar originates.

On Windows extensions are special, and it seems the `unrar` code treats it as sort-of-not-really part of the filename—a plain, final trailing `*` will match one, but a `*` in the middle will not. Not sure if this is expected behavior on Windows, but its surely not on Unix.

---

**Workaround**

The sane way to deal with brokenness like this is probably something like:

```shell
for f in file*rar; do
    unrar x "$f"
done
```

Let the shell expand the glob and give unrar one file at a time. Just hope none of your files have `*` in their names...

---

<sup>I at first said it worked in 5.2.7, that was mistaken: I lost the backslash while testing…</sup>

Answer (score 4):

```
unrar x '*.rar'
```

this works for me, I had the same issue.

if I omitt the ' unrar will try to add all the files on the same command line

ex : I have 1.rar 2.rar 3.rar
if I do

`unrar x *.rar`

the command pass to linux will be

```
unrar x 1.rar  2.rar 3.rar
```

and result in an error
but if I use the ' like this

```
unrar x '*.rar'
```

the command passed will be

```
unrar x 1.rar
unrar x 2.rar
.......
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enter `unrar x file\*rar`, the unrar program receives the
literal string `file*rar`. It's probably easier to just enter `unrar x file*rar`, which will cause your shell to expand the pattern (`unrar`
will receive the list of files that match the pattern).

Now, how come `unrar x file\*rar` doesn't work while e.g. `unrar x
file\*.rar` does? My guess would be that `unrar` includes its own code
to do pattern expansion, to run on systems where the shell doesn't do
it, and the rules are not the same as on Unix. If I remember
correctly, that would match the rules on MS-DOS, where `*rar` will
*not* match files with names that end in `.rar`.

Comment: `file*rar` doesn't work. `unrar` takes the first file argument as the archive, then the rest as (I'd guess) which files to extract from the archive—not as additional archives to extract.

Comment: @derobert: My (admittedly old) version of unrar in fact appears to handle all arguments to `x` as rar archives. I wrote that `unrar x file\*.rar` works (note the dot, it definitely doesn't work without it).

Comment: Ah, nice to know different unrar versions behave differently. (You may also have the very ancient free version of unrar, that could be quite different. After all, someone may have patched it to behave sanely, unlike the non-free version...)